# when will firebase database disabled after exceeds the downloads limit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a project on firebase . It's in spark plan.I have exceeds the limit of real-time database downloads . I am currently getting warning "the database will be disabled if no action is taken" but this message didn't determine when exactly will it disabled. Will it disabled after a specific time or after the downloads increases to a specific number or what exactly?

Note : I am connecting a prepaid card to my Google cloud billing but it's not allowed in firebase but can they use it instead of disabling the database?

Comment: I would recommend contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/) for assistance with this.

Comment: You shouldn't delete that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225667/servertime-stamp-is-uploaded-as-string-in-cloud-fire-store). I was on my way to write you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted firebase support team and they told me that disabling the database is done by the system so there is no specific time for that

Comment: after the end of the month, the plan initialized again ??

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI yes thats true. you will get monthly quota renewed every month

Comment: @QadirHussain so if the system disables it, on the next month, it will be re-enabled?

Comment: @Oush yes this is true. It will be enabled automatically